# How to assure that we still are in feasible set during optimization iterations?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

What are methods to force the point remains in the optimization domain ,other than taking projection step after each iteration?I haven't find any other solution for this but this projection step seems to slow down the algorithm.The problem is minimizing $f(x)+g(z)$(using ADMM method) such that $Ax+Bz+b=0$ and $g$ is the indicator function of a set $c$,and I mean that in iterations some time $z$ is not in $c$ as a result $g(z)$ becomes infinity and the algorithm give back $z=NaN$, so I need to turn back into c after each iteration.any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Provide more details.

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid Every time the point pop out the feasible set I have to calculate it's projection on the feasible set which is an optimization problem itself,I wonder if there is some more efficient way to deal with this situation

Comment: @MAh2014 what algorithm are we looking at? Limiting the step length is another common method.

Comment: in ADMM, the linking constraints (that link the two sets of variables from the two terms of the objective function) will typically not be satisfied during the iterations.  Are you talking about those constraints or some other constraints?  Please give us your problem and describe the method you're trying to use to solve it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include all of these details.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I just added the details.

Answer (score 0):

When $g(z)$ is the indicator function of a convex set $C$, then in the associated minimization step of the ADMM method, you'll be finding a $z$ in $C$ that also minimizes the augmented Lagrangian term

$\min_{z \in C} \frac{\rho}{2} \| Bz - (Ax+b) \|_{2}^{2}$

This is the minimization of a quadratic function over $C$.  Your procedure for doing this must return a $z$ in $C$.  There aren't any other steps of the algorithm that would change $z$.